# Wikipedia version of Mertens' 3rd theorem

Tags: number-theory, limits, prime-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

I have a questiom regarding the Wikipedia's formula about Mertens' 3rd Theorem.

While [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems) Wikipedia's article describes it by using the natural logarithm of n, [this other](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) (exponential section) talks about using the natural log of the nth prime number.

Which one would be the correct one? Why?

Thank you!

Comment: $\ln p_n \sim \ln n$ and this follows form the 1st  or  2nd Mertens theorem

Comment: The first one. In the second link it is said that this is a "restatement" of Mertens' third theorem.

Comment: But, in fact, I think that the "restatement" comes from elevating the limit to -1 and changing Euler's constant to its positive value